# Post object via CURL using PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

We are attempting to post to a rest API endpoint that requires a "POST object" within one of the keys. In javascript/jquery, this works fine. But, using CURL in PHP the endpoint doesn't receive the object (called "components") here:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.sitesitesite.com');

    $comps = array('slug' => "xyz",
                   'visble' => 1,
                   'color' => "xyz",
                   'shape' => "xyz",
                   'version' => "2",
            );

    $post_args = array();
    $post_args['components'] = $comps;
    $post_args['id'] = $id;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_args);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Try adding `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));` to the headers

Comment: @kuncajs CURLOPT_POST *should* do that for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of "CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST" and use "CURLOPT_POST"

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```